# RandomizedDelaySec + Persistent after wakeup

Tags: systemd

I run the backups for my desktop computer via systemd. Using

```
OnCalendar = daily
Persistent = true
RandomizedDelaySec = 10m
```

causes the backup to run once every day. If the computer is powered of, the backup runs after the next boot.

The problem is, if I suspend the computer, the backup tries to run immediately after wakeup without any delay. Since the network connection takes a few seconds, the backup fails.

I think this should be handled by `RandomizedDelaySec`, but its set at timer creation. How can I tell systemd to wait after wakeup?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#RandomizedDelaySec=), `RandomizedDelaySec=` will "Delay the timer by a randomly selected, evenly distributed amount of time between 0 and the specified time value."

So you really don't want to depend on `RandomizedDelaySec=` for something where you need a delay because 0m is a very real possibility.

Normally, `RandomizedDelaySec=` does work well with `Persistent=`, but I'm not really sure how it reacts to "suspend" because I'm not sure that the system is ever considered to be stopped during that state.  I think troubleshooting this suspend-use-case is a red herring.

Instead, you have two options:

1. Manually add `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep ...` to your backup service to ensure a minimum delay, or
2. Add `After=network.target` to your timer or service, or perhaps `After=mymount.mount` if you are waiting for your custom `fuse.sshfs` mount to come up.

Option 1 is a simple catch-all case. But I'm not normally a fan of `sleep` because on a slow-day you're waiting for nothing, and on a busy-day, you may not be waiting long enough. There's no feedback to the actual state of what you're waiting on for perfect timing. But since this is a background, non-time-critical task, it's probably fine to wait 10 minutes extra, even for days where you are not suspended.